# bash string expansion for grep -E expression in single quotes

Tags: bash, grep

Within a bash script I am trying to construct a string for `grep -E` so that it appears as

```
grep -E 'alice|bar|bob|foo'
```

If I test the grep at the command line-- `ls * | grep -E  'alice|bar|bob|foo'`-- things work as expected.  It excludes all the files with the same name as the list within the extended regular expression.

The issue I've found is that it will not match the first and last strings within a bash script if I construct the string as `'alice|bar|bob|foo'`

Broken testcase:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch foo.txt bar.txt alice.txt bob.txt
touch alice.tmp bob.tmp foo.tmp crump.tmp dammitall.tmp
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=$(echo *.txt | sed 's/\.txt /|/g' | sed 's/\.txt//')
EXCLUDE_PATTERN="'""$EXCLUDE_PATTERN""'"
echo "Excluding files that match the string $EXCLUDE_PATTERN"

for file in *.tmp
do
  if echo $file | grep -q -E $EXCLUDE_PATTERN
  then
    echo "Keeping $file"
  else 
    echo "Deleting $file"
    rm -f $file
  fi
done
```

Outputs:

```
Excluding files that match the string 'alice|bar|bob|foo'
Deleting alice.tmp
Keeping bob.tmp
Deleting crump.tmp
Deleting dammitall.tmp
Deleting foo.tmp
```

... and yet I don't want it do delete alice.tmp or foo.tmp because they're in the regex!

I assume the shell is getting some characters that it's not when the string is expanded in this script, but I can't for the life of me figure out in what manner the string passed to `grep -E` is getting hosed by the "broken" script above.

Variations like `EXCLUDE_PATTERN="'$EXCLUDE_PATTERN'"` don't seem to help.  Haven't found the magic string.

Edit to include useful comment below:

Using `set -x` indicates that bash does the single-quote wrapping itself, so the incorrect code above does this `EXCLUDE_PATTERN=''\''alice|bar|bob|foo'\'''` which is just adding single quotes around single quotes.

Comment: the shell is "seeing" your `|` chars as pipes. use `if echo ... grep .. "$EXCLUDE_PAT"` (note the dbl-quotes around your var name). AND, don't bother with `EX_PAT="'""$EX_PAT""'"`, just 1 set of dbl-quotes should do. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you adding the single quote marks?  Just remove this line:

```
 EXCLUDE_PATTERN="'""$EXCLUDE_PATTERN""'"
```

I'm getting the following without that line:

```
 Excluding files that match the string alice|bar|bob|foo
 Keeping alice.tmp
 Keeping bob.tmp
 Deleting crump.tmp
 Deleting dammitall.tmp
 Keeping foo.tmp
```

Comment: You're right, that works.  I'm adding them because they're needed at the command line.  Why the difference?  (Also many thanks! This is one of those things where I've ended up in a morass of dicking with escape chars until losing track of what permutations I'd tried...)

Comment: At the command prompt, the single quotes prevent the pipes from being used to redirect the I/O, but are not passed onto `grep`.  When the quotes are part of the variable's values, then they are passed on when the variable is expanded (and part of the regex).

Comment: Add the command `set -x` at the beginning of your script .. this will instruct bash to show you how it's expanding variables and starting subprocesses.  It's a very useful trick I used all the time to debug these types of problems.

Comment: You should use double-quotes around variable references, though (e.g. `grep -q -E "$EXCLUDE_PATTERN"`), because the shell does *some* parsing of substituted values (just not parsing quotes in the variable's value). You'll get away without the double-quotes in this case, but it's best to get in the habit of using them whenever you use a variable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson probably passed through there on my way here.  I just find it non-intuitive that the single-quotes are necessary at the cmdline to get the expression passed as a single argument, but not in the evaluation of that line of script.

Comment: @stevesliva: it has to do with the order in which bash parses various elements of the command line. Specifically, it parses quotes before expanding variables, so putting quotes *in* a variable's value doesn't do anything useful -- by the time the quotes are part of the command, it's too late for them to do what you meant them to. Putting (double-)quotes *around* the variable reference, on the other hand, does do something very useful.